# How do I determine the Java EE version of JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1 and I need to determine the Java EE version that is provided. I'm pretty sure that it is Java EE 6. But how can I determine the version number and how can I switch to Java EE 7 which is released since May 2013?

Comment: Please, http://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/articles/113373

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I'm using JBoss AS7.1 and I need to determine the Java EE version that is provided. I'm pretty sure that it is Java EE 6. But how can I determine the version number*

Just read the release notes of server in question. Here's the [JBoss AS 7.1 release notes](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AS710FinalReleaseNotes).

---

> *and how can I switch to Java EE 7 which is released since May 2013?*

By replacing JBoss AS 7.1 by another make/version which implements Java EE 7. So far,  JBoss AS has no production-ready Java EE 7 compatible server. [JBoss AS 8](http://planet.jboss.org/post/java_ee_7_and_ejb_3_2_support_in_jboss_as_8) ([Wildfly](http://www.wildfly.org/)) is still in [alpha](http://www.wildfly.org/download/) stage. As of now, [GlassFish 4](https://glassfish.java.net/) is the only "production-ready" server which implements Java EE 7. In quotes, because I find it rather buggy. Better wait for 4.0.1 (if it ever comes out) or a 4.1.

Comment: Major new versions of GlassFish are always buggy for real use. They are focused above all to implement the Java EE spec. "Suitable for production" is a secondary concern. With Java EE 6 it was the same story.